# Can "all" in "all alone" be used in the same way for other adjectives, too? For example, can we say "He was all sad."?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

**"You were all alone."**

I understand that the structure **"all+adjective"** means **"so, very, completely, etc"**. So I wondered if we can use **"all"** in the same way with other ajdectives, too, Or is it specific to some adjectives only, like **"all alone".**?

For example, can we say:

- He was **all sad** yesterday.
- The room was **all black** that I couldn't see anything when I walked in.
- The price was **all cheap**.
- The grass was **all green.**
- The sky was **all blue.**
- The car was **all fast**.

Comment: Sad, black, green, blue,: yes; cheap, fast: no.

Comment: I don't find **all sad** idiomatic, and I would understand 'all green grass' and an 'all blue sky' as being without any patches of another colour rather than 'very green/blue'.